# Is this a pressfit bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket, press-fit

https://www.highonbikes.com/products/token-ninja-thread-fit-bottom-bracket-bb386-to-shimano-24mm

Is this a pressfit BB? Also, how is this different from: https://www.merlincycles.com/token-ninja-bottom-bracket-bb386-for-shimano-24mm-134140.html

They're both Token Ninja and the one from Merlin Cycles is less expensive.

Comment: Same unit, different photos

Comment: Please don’t try to bump your thread, particularly not by stating that the forum seems dead. People here work for free, so we are not obligated to respond to any particular thread. If the question is answerable, someone will answer it eventually.

Comment: In addition to what Weiwen mentioned, note that this site isn’t Facebook or something. People actually take the time to research and write good answers. On other websites in the stack exchange network, there are some serious (like PhD level) questions being answered.

Answer (score 3):

They seem to be the same, or at least equivalent – note the RRP is the same for both. They will both work in a BB386 press-fit bottom bracket shell, but they are installed by threading (rather than pressing) the two halves together, hence the spline interface. You will need a tool that fits these splines to install it.

Comment: They both look very different, there has to be a difference between them

Comment: @Sam The color :D

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that the web listings may have incorrect photos and incorrect details. Don't trust the photos implicitly, you should contact the seller before purchase if you have any doubts. They will say errors or omissions are not their problem, but equally, UK distance selling regulations protect UK buyers IANAL.

---

The Merlin Cycles page lists the product code as TK-DBBTF38624

I.E. it is listed as a TF38624 model. Contemporary models are black so it may be  an old colour variant(?)

The High on Bikes page, I don't see a product code but the photo is of a TF37 model.

On the Token website it says,

> The NINJA bottom bracket is can be purchased individually or in a package that includes adapters to fit several different frame and crankset combinations

This seems to be the difference between them, one is dedicated to BB386, 24mm and one comes with adapters to match different frames to various chainsets. note that the TF37 shows an adapter on the right hand side.

---

That said, consider the RRP of both units is the same. The RRP of TF37 is higher on other websites so maybe it's not actually TF37 after all.

Comment: Ah, so the TK-DBBTF38624 will only work with cranks with 24mm diameter spindle and the TF37 works with cranks with any size diameter spindle?

Comment: potentially. Token's website has all the specs. However, neither photo lines up exactly with the current photos on Token's website and the High on Bikes website merely claims BB386 to shimano 24 mm. So now you know as much as me

Answer (score 2):

You would read a BB spec by looking for a shell type, e.g. BB 386, and then a spindle type, e.g. Shimano. Spindles differ in diameter, so the BBs have to be different or to use a reducer kit (e.g. I think a lot of GXP BBs probably were Shimano BBs with a 2mm reducer on the non-drive side). You have that info.

You asked if the BB was press fit. It is. You identified two thread-together BBs. They go in press fit shells, but you thread one half into the other. This design can help with creaking. I don’t think this is a critical feature unless your BB shell has exhibited this problem; even then, creaking probably means your shell is a bit out of tolerance, and a thread-together unit isn’t guaranteed to fix that.

If the units were different in MSRP, you would look for other important features of the specs. For example, maybe one BB had some sort of bearing upgrade. This would be the most common difference, but bearing upgrades tend to cost a lot more than £5. As stated elsewhere, these are likely the same BB but different market prices. Remember that most manufacturers don’t strictly control the sales price of their products, and some legal jurisdictions may actually prohibit this practice. To verify that they’re the same BB, you could look for a manufacturer product code in the listings.